# OpenNetCf SDF not returning all adapters

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, opennetcf

When calling GetAllNetworkInterfaces() via:

```
INetworkInterface[] rgni = WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

I'm only getting back a single adapter back, RNDISFN1, which has a link-local address (169.254....).
I suspect something bad is happening to cause all of the adapters to not be populated in the array; under the debugger, when I fire off the function, I'm seeing:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in CSharpSample.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in OpenNETCF.Net.dll
A first chance exception of type 'OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException' occurred in OpenNETCF.Net.dll
```

To be clear, the end goal of this is to get a list of Wireless Profiles, and have the ability to switch between them.

For now, has anybody seen instances where GetAllNetworkInterfaces() doesn't return all of the adapters? I am using version OpenNetCF SDF v2.3 under Windows Mobile 6.

Comment: What type of hardware is this on?  How does the result change when you run the same code when *not* attached via ActiveSync?

Comment: Chris -- good point; ActiveSync had the radio disabled. If I force the radio on, I see the adapter in the list. Sadly, OpenNetCF (and, I'm sure, the Win API's), see this adapter as ethernet; I can not cast it to a WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface or a WirelessNetworkInterface.

Comment: @Chris: This is running on a Socket Mobile 650. With regard to my secondary comment (why I see it as ethernet), I still haven't applied the latest Socket service pack to this unit. It's possible that the adapter will advertise itself as WZC afterward.

Comment: @Chris: Just applied the latest SP; no change; still reporting as ethernet. Either way, your answer of "you're cradled, the wifi is off" turned out to answer my original question. If you post an answer with the same info, I'll award it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you see a single adapter (and I can tell by the name) indicates that you're cradled.  ActiveSync, in all its glory, shuts down all other radios when cradled and therefore no other radios will show up.  Run the code when not cradled and you'll likely see your WiFi (and any other) adapters appear.